# Who is "he" is Genesis 15:6b?

Tags: greek, genesis, hebrew, septuagint

Without taking in consideration the exegesis of Paul and James of this text, how do we know that the "he" in

> and he counted it to him as righteousness.  Genesis 15:6b

is God?

Hebrew text for Genesis 15:6 :

> וְהֶאֱמִ֖ן בַּֽיהוָ֑ה וַיַּחְשְׁבֶ֥הָ לֹּ֖ו צְדָקָֽה׃

Greek text (LXX) for Genesis 15:6 :

> καὶ ἐπίστευσεν Αβραμ τῷ θεῷ καὶ ἐλογίσθη αὐτῷ εἰς δικαιοσύνην

I ask this question because some can say that Genesis 15:6 says "And he believed the LORD, and he counted it (what God said) as true.